# Error while trying to build my kernel in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, kernel

I am trying to compile something on my system, but it requires first to build my kernel ...

anyhow I went to the kernel directory and build it by typing make command and got this error ..

```
 CHK     include/linux/version.h
 CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
 make[1]: *** No rule to make target `kernel/bounds.c', needed by `kernel/bounds.s'.  Stop.
```

I googled it of course and all the threads which contain the same error suggested almots the same thing , I tried them with no use...

for example [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1047374.html) ..

Can anyone familiar with the problem help me ?

P.S. I do have the file bounds.s but not .c and my kernel version is :

linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic

Comment: It needs `bounds.c` and can't find it. As for *why* you're missing `bounds.c`, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you do not have the complete source. bounds.c should be in /usr/src/linux-source-2.6.38/kernel.

```
    xxxxx@ubuntu:/usr/src/linux-source-2.6.32/kernel$ ls bounds.c
    bounds.c
    xxxxx@ubuntu:/usr/src/linux-source-2.6.32/kernel$
```

I would go back to square one and get the source and deflate, then check for bounds.c. There are 100's of files in the archive and you may be missing others if your missing one.